# how to calculate pf on salary in gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

How I can calculate pf on salary in c# at  gridview bind or after gridview bind

```
private void BindEmpGrid()
{      
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_emp", con);
    adp.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grdEmp.DataSource = dt;

        grdEmp.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        grdEmp.DataSource = null;

        grdEmp.DataBind();
    }
}
```

in table i have salary column

Salary
12000
15390
27494
19300
49028

how i calculate pf 5% on each salary row

Comment: What is a PF and what are the rules for calculating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to calculate a PF salary

1. MSSQL QUERY
2. Dynamic column creation

easiest way is Using MSSQL query.

For example:

```
select id,name,basicpay,bascicpay*0.05 as PF from tbl_emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ;

```
  "select salary * 0.05 AS NewSalary from tbl_emp";
```